# Sum all value in a tree data

Tags: javascript

Here is the input arr:

```
const  arr = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
  { id: 12, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
  { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];
```

I need to format the arrays. Use  recursive  function, the value of "total" in parent node = sum all the value of "total" in childs node. The expected output will be:

```
[
  { id: 1 , total: 5}, 
  { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
  { id: 12, parent_id: 1, total: 3 }, 
  { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
  { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];
```

Comment: Why would the total be `3` for the element with id `12` when it's a leaf node?

Comment: I'm new to js: maybe you wanna learn JS first?

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks for reminding, it was my mistake. Edited

Comment: @Slevin i'm still learning

Comment: The task you want to achieve is to add the value named 'total' when it does not appeared?

Comment: @mad-hin: not really, i need to do it in a onChange event (change the "total" of the leaf) . So first, the parent node doesnot have property "total". but after the first onChange event trigger, the parent node will have "total". And i need to caculate the "total" of parent node everytime it change

Comment: @VuPhan thanks for accepting, you could also upvote my answer (the arrow up) to reward my efforts, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only leaf nodes contain `total`:

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
    { id: 12, parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
    { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];

// collect items into an array by ID for further tree walking
const map = {};

for (const item of arr) {
    map[item.id] = item;
}

// we have totals only in leaf nodes so filter them and iterate
for (const item of arr.filter(item => 'total' in item)) {

    // walk through parents of a leaf node and add to their totals
    let parent = item;
    while (parent = map[parent.parent_id]) {
        parent.total = 'total' in parent ? parent.total + item.total : item.total;
    }

}

arr.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```

Otherwise find leaf nodes (this is also for updating parents when some leaf is changed):

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 1, total: 100 },
    { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
    { id: 12, parent_id: 1, total: 1000 },
    { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
    { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];

// collect items into an array by ID for further tree walking
const map = {};
// find parent IDs to filter leaf nodes
const parentIds = new Set;

for (const item of arr) {
    map[item.id] = item;
    parentIds.add(item.parent_id);
}

const touchedParents = new Set;

// we have totals only in leaf nodes so filter them and iterate
for (const item of arr.filter(item => !parentIds.has(item.id))) {

    // walk through parents of a leaf node and add to their totals
    // if the total isn't updated (touched) yet, init it
    let parent = item;
    while (parent = map[parent.parent_id]) {
        touchedParents.has(parent) ? parent.total += item.total : touchedParents.add(parent) && (parent.total = item.total);
    }

}

arr.forEach(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)));
```

Answer (score 3):

ok so for this you need to consider following things:

1. first find out all nodes that are parent nodes.
2. for each parent node, you need to sum the total values of its child nodes.
3. if a child node doesn't have a total value, then its total is the sum of its own child nodes.
4. if a node doesn't have a total and also doesn't have any child nodes, then it doesn't contribute to the total of its parent node.

```js
function sumTree(arr) {
    let map = {};
    let root;

    // Create nodes map and find root
    for(let obj of arr) {
        map[obj.id] = {...obj, total: obj.total || 0, children: []};
        if(!obj.parent_id) root = map[obj.id];
    }

    // Build tree
    for(let obj of arr) {
        if(obj.parent_id) {
            map[obj.parent_id].children.push(map[obj.id]);
        }
    }

    // Function to calculate total recursively
    function calculateTotal(node) {
        for(let child of node.children) {
            calculateTotal(child);
            node.total += child.total;
        }
    }

    calculateTotal(root);

    // Function to convert the tree back to an array
    function flattenTree(node) {
        let res = [];
        for(let child of node.children) {
            res = res.concat(flattenTree(child));
        }
        return [{id: node.id, parent_id: node.parent_id, total: node.total}].concat(res);
    }

    return flattenTree(root);
}

const arr = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
  { id: 12, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
  { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];

console.log(sumTree(arr));
```

Comment: Thank u for the help, but it was not really work. Because the input arr is 
const  arr = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
  { id: 12, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
  { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];

and the example tree data is just 2 level. In the global problem, i need to handle a tree data with n level

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i expected the tree to be in order. Please check the edit, i modified the code to be in depth first order, so that parents appear before children.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, We should transform it to a tree, This mindset can help us develop a good habit of thinking in terms of data structures

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 11, parent_id: 1, total: 2 },
  { id: 12, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 121, parent_id: 12, total: 1 },
  { id: 122, parent_id: 12, total: 2 }
];

function buildTree(arr) {
  const tree = [];

  const map = new Map();
  for (const item of arr) {
    map.set(item.id, { ...item, children: [] });
  }

  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item.parent_id) {
      const parent = map.get(item.parent_id);
      if (parent) {
        parent.children.push(map.get(item.id));
      }
    } else {
      tree.push(map.get(item.id));
    }
  }

  const calculateTotal = (node) => {
    let total = node.total || 0;
    for (const child of node.children) {
      total += calculateTotal(child);
    }
    node.total = total;
    return total;
  };

  for (const node of tree) {
    calculateTotal(node);
  }

  return tree;
}

const tree = buildTree(arr);
```

Then you can use DFS to print out your idea result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).